# laravel update ordenado por la ultima fecha de registro

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hola buenas y gracias a quien me pueda ayudar de antemano.
No puedo conseguir lo siguiente, tengo dos tablas en la primera 'user' quiero actualizar el campo 'subscription_type' comparando la fecha actual con el campo de otra tabla llamada 'quota' que tengo un campo 'end_date' este campo se compara con la fecha actual y si es menor se ha de hacer el update, el código que tengo funciona solo que tiene un problema que como se guardan varios registros con el mismo user_id para llevar un control de una subscripción el update no me toma el ultimo y me actualiza siempre que encuentra una fecha inferior a la actual.

```
 public function handle()
    {
        $timestamp = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
       
        
        Users::join('quota','quota.user_id', '=','users.user_id') 
        ->where('quota.end_date','<',$timestamp)->orderBy('quota.end_date', 'asc' )
        ->where('status','!=','deleted')
        ->update(['subscription_type'=>'Free']);
 
     
    }
```

Tabla User:

```
 id user_id subscription_type 

  1  1      pro
  2  2      fre
  3  3      pro
```

Tabla quota

```
id. user_id. start_date    end_date
1   1       2021-1-22     2021-2-22
2   2       2021-5-22     2021-6-22
3   3       2021-9-12     2022-1-12
4   1       2021-11-3     2021-12-3
```

quiero que subscription_type de la tabla user se actualice si por ejemplo la fecha end_date es menor a la actual pero que me lea solo el ultimo registro del user_id de la tabla quota que es la subscripción actual de ese user.
Claro ahora me actualiza el user_id 1 y no debería ya que su ultimo registro la fecha end_date todavía no ha pasado pero me lee supongo el registro anterior.

Comment: Si logro entenderte, para ordenar de forma **descendente** los registros (el más alto primero) dado un campo de tipo **timestamp** debes usar `orderBy('quota.end_date', 'desc')`

Comment: bueno gracias en verdad es el ultimo registro , eso probé y no funciona llevo toda la tarde probando cosas y nada no se cual seria la forma correcta.

Comment: Okey okey creo ya entender tu problema, si lo que quieres es actualizar solo un registro debes añadir `->limit(1)` antes de tu `update()` el orden como te lo he explicado es correcto, pero claro al hacer eso estás actualizando todos los registros que consiga con esa condición. Si solo quieres actualizar el último, limita la consulta a un registro, de lo contrario no tendría sentido el **orderBy**

Comment: Bueno quiero actualizar cualquiera que cumpla esa condición ya que pueden haber mas usuarios con esa condición pero si tiene que ser el último registro de ese usuario.

Comment: tiene que ser el ultimo registro de cada usuario, ya que cada usuario puede tener mas de un registro  la tabla que actualizo es user y la que quiero obtener la fecha es quota son diferentes.

Comment: Bien, estoy un poco confundido,  si quieres actualizar la tabla **users**, cada usuario debería tener un campo `subscription_type` a menos que ese campo este en `quota`, allí el problema es un poco más complejo pero obviamente tiene solución . Por favor te suplico que edites tu pregunta explicando, en la medida de lo posible, un poco mejor lo que quieres hacer, tal vez añadiendo la estructura de ambas tablas

Comment: ¿Por qué no usas relaciones en vez de **joins**?

Comment: Bueno es que no se mucho de programación ahora pongo un poco como son las tablas lo edito en la pregunta

Comment: Bien no te preocupes, buscaremos la solución solo necesito entender esto, muchas gracias

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131208/discussion-between-josbert-and-luana).

Answer (score 1):

Bien analizando tu problema, logre entenderlo y dar con una solución.

Básicamente, cada usuario tiene una *suscripción* que vence en una fecha determinada, como me habías comentado tienes una [Task Scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling) que deberia actulizar a `free` la suscripción de los usuarios, a los que les haya vencido la misma.

Para poder obtener los usuarios, en donde el campo `end_date` de su tabla relacionada `quota` sea menor a la fecha actual, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

**Ya que no estas usando las [Relaciones de Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)**

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

public function handle()
{
   // No es del todo necesario obtener la fecha actual usando format() de esta manera pero ya que es un campo de tipo date, lo haré así
   $timestamp = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
  
   // Traemos solo los usuarios que estén relacionados con la tabla quota
   // Que además el campo end_date, del ultimo registro, sea menor a la fecha actual
   Users::whereExists(function($query){
      $query->select('*')
      ->from('quota')
      ->whereColumn('users.user_id', 'quota.user_id');
   })
   ->where( DB::raw("(SELECT end_date FROM `quota` WHERE `users`.`user_id` = `quota`.`user_id` ORDER BY DESC LIMIT 1)"), '<', $timestamp )
   ->where('status','!=','deleted')
   ->update([
      'subscription_type' => 'Free'
   ]);
}
```

Gracias a la clausura **[Where Exists](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#where-exists-clauses)** podemos condicionar con su relación en la tabla `quota`,seleccionando usuarios en donde su última suscripción esté vencida o mejor dicho, el campo `end_date` sea menor a la fecha actual

Como ya te había contado, todo esto sería más fácil usando **Eloquent relationships** o las relaciones de **Eloquent**

Espero haberte ayudado, un saludo :D

Comment: Bien acabo de corregir un pequeño error que tuve, una disculpa, ahora hago uso de [Una expresión en crudo, DB::raw()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions) para crear una condición personalizada dado un campo en su relación, por favor prueba esto y me cuentas

Comment: vale creo que este no me funciona, pero tengo que mirar con mas detalle

Comment: Debería funcionar, en caso de que no, cuéntame que error te da para ver que puede estar fallando

Comment: Hola Josbert no me sale ningún error pero no se no me hace nada.

Comment: Primero debes asegurarte que tu consulta realmente trae algún registro, cambia el `update([...])` por un `count()` y luego ve que te retorna. Segundo ¿en tu modelo `Users` está el campo `subscription_type` dentro de la propiedad `$fillable`? para asignación masiva

Comment: Hola subscription_type esta dentro de $fillable, lo que no se ver hacer la consulta para ver si me trae algún registro.

Answer (score 0):

Hola encontré una solución no se si será la mejor forma ni si me dara problemas en un futuro si alguien puede mejorar por favor que ayude, y Josbert muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

He creado otro campo en la tabla quota llamado 'status_quota' tipo enum('active','disabled') por defecto los registros se crearan con este campo en active es decir subscripción activa.

```
public function handle()
{
    $timestamp = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
   
    
    Users::join('quota','quota.user_id', '=','users.user_id') 
    ->where('quota.status_quota', '!=', 'disable')
    ->where('quota.end_date','<',$timestamp)
    ->where('status','!=','deleted')
    ->update(['subscription_type'=>'Free','quota.status_quota'=>'disable']);
}
```

Entonces le pongo la condición que mire los registros con status_quota diferente a disable. y realizo un doble update de la tabla Users subscription_type y de quota status_quota.

con esto parece que me funciona bien. Si alguien ve algun error o puede mejorar lo agradecería.